# Gitea Docker Registry - Unauthorized on first login?

Tags: docker-registry, podman, unauthorized, gitea

I have a Jenkins pipeline where a Docker (Podman) image is built und pushed to a private Gitea docker registry. This basically works. But I have the problem, that the first build after several hours, that means on the next day, crashes because pushing to the Gitea registry leads to:

```
Error: writing blob: uploading layer to https://192.168.0.5:4000/v2/myorg/myproject/blobs/uploads/ptuh7yizsrqvx5wlg9uctlzdv?digest=sha256%3A7ca0dabc572c112e5141bac7e5f29a0c1b1f727ce939ac1e7da342d3adf324a: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

When I click on the link, it shows me:

```
errors  
0   
code    "UNAUTHORIZED"
message ""
```

Since I trigger the login from a remote host via Jenkins pipeline, I do that with a script, but I'm pretty sure that this does not matter. The content at the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
podman login -u builderuser -p builderpassword 192.168.0.5:4000
```

I see in the logs that `Login Succeeded!`, but after the next step, I get the error from above after it tries to copy the blob to the registry.

I also tried to add a "logout" before login in the script via

```
podman logout 192.168.0.5:4000
```

But this does not help either.

When I trigger the same build again, the process works without problems. Maybe some caching problem anywhere? The problem appears at the first build on the next day, so I guess there is some session timeout anywhere after several hours. Any ideas?

**[UPDATE]**

I think this is a bug in Gitea. In log I see this:

```
Nov 11 08:50:40 server gitea[34985]: 2022/11/11 08:50:40 ...es/container/blob.go:66:func1() [E] [636dfed0-7] Error inserting package: pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint »UQE_package_version_s«
```

And in code of Gitea in auths.go, I see a comment leading me to the assumption that they are aware of this problem:

```
// FIXME: if the name conflicts, it will result in 500: Error 1062: Duplicate entry 'aa' for key 'login_source.UQE_login_source_name'
```

What I still don't understand is, why this happens only once, at the beginning of the day, and not always.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the logs on the registry?

If you get something like

> <path>/registry/docker: permission denied

it means the error happens if your user does not have the permission to write.

If on the permission side you're ok, than the error shown is quite random and has the same root cause as [gitlab-org/gitlab#215715](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/215715)
The error has been fixed for gitlab. You'd need to check on Jenkins if they have some open issues similar to this.